# scrape webpage and save as CSV with BS4 and Pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas, raspberry-pi

Normally I use R when I **scrape** a webpage & save the result in a csv file.
This is very easy in R, but my R code doesn't work on my Raspberry Pi because of some incompatibilities between Raspbian and one of the packages. So I decided try to do my work in Python.

It's very easy what I want to do: **scrape** title, link and image link from local news webpage and save as csv.

Everything is OK when I try my code in a Jupyter notebook (on Windows), the csv file has a nice data frame with 12 rows, but when I try my code on my Raspberry the csv file contains only one row.

This is my first python code, except "many Hello world" so I know that it is not perfect, but I am completely stuck why it doesn't run on Raspberry

Thanks for any help

```
# coding: utf-8
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
r = urllib.urlopen('http://krakow.tvp.pl/554275/aktualnosci').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(r,'html.parser')
aktualnosci = soup.find_all("div", class_={"recommended","item hidden","image border-radius-5","meta cf","title"})
tytuly = soup.find_all("li", class_ = "border-radius-5")

prefix="http://krakow.tvp.pl"
link_aktualnosci = []
link_grafika_aktualnosci = []
link_tytul_aktualnosci = []
#course = []
temp = []
courses_list = []

for item in aktualnosci:
    temp1 = item.a['href'] # pobieram link do artykulu
    link_aktualnosci.append(temp1.encode('UTF-8'))
    
    temp2 = item.img.get('src') # pobieram link do grafiki
    link_grafika_aktualnosci.append(temp2.encode('UTF-8'))

    
    temp3 = item.find('span',class_="title").text.strip().encode('UTF-8') # pobieram tekst tytułu
    link_tytul_aktualnosci.append(temp3)
    
    temp = [temp1,temp2,temp3]
    courses_list.append(temp)

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(courses_list)

df.to_csv('aktualnosci.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't test this now; I don't have Python installed.  But...does this work for you?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_html('http://krakow.tvp.pl/554275/aktualnosci', 
    header=0, 
    index_col=0)[2]
print (df)
```